# PayPal Subscription API, Smart Payment Button and custom variables

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to set up a recurring payment with PayPal Subscription REST API. I'm following the Basic Integration in PayPal Developer Portal, using as suggested the Smart Payment Button. Besides, I'm using a WebHook to "capture" events related to subscription.
As the tutoria suggest, I created a Product and a Plan. 
Now, I rendered the Smart Payment Button in a page (using the example), and when clicked it triggers the PayPal authorization flow. When the user complete the subscription process, the `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED` event is triggered. Later, also the `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` and `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` are triggered, and I receive data in my WebHook. Now, I have troubles in identifying which user activated the subscription. My idea is to pass a custom variable (with something allows me to identify the user) and retrive it later when the WebHook post me data, but I can't undertand how to do it. Anyway, is this the best way to do it? Or there is another solution?

Comment: hey Racchio did you solve this?

Comment: I would also like to know more about this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using "custom_id" in the smart button:

```
return actions.subscription.create({
  'plan_id': 'PLAN_ID',
  'custom_id': 'CUSTOM_ID'
});
```

Then, I receive `custom_id` from webhooks or querying the subscription.